# Uploading image to blogspot using JavaScript and blogger API

Tags: javascript, blogger

I have created my Google API Console and already get client-ID and Client Secret code.
By Using both of them, how do I upload an image and saved in blogger with URL bp.blogspot.

I have already tried this but not sure how to use it for image:

```
{
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "blog": {
    "id": "8070105920543249955"
  },
  "title": "A new post",
  "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
}
```

As guided in https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348829/how-to-attach-an-image-with-blog-post-google-blogger-api-c-sharp-vb-net#19355259 (though it doesn't mention JS, it might be the only chance)

Comment: have you solved the problem?